Why is my text misaligned in my .rdl report
I'm making an .rdl report in visual studio 2019, which gets uploaded to Dynamics, and then users export the file to pdf.
The two top text boxes, for Variety Name and Eating experience have the same code, with html markup, which I understood to override the properties text requirements. The font was correctly Roboto, but misaligned (see photo below, left side.)
The code was the same, the padding on the cell was the same (5pt all around.)
="<span style='color:gray; font-weight:bold; font-size:10pt; font-family: Roboto;'>VARIETY NAME:</span><br/><span style='color:black; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Roboto;'>" & Fields!new_varietyname.Value & "</span>"
="<span style='color:gray; font-weight:bold; font-size:10pt; font-family: Roboto;'>EATING EXPERIENCE:</span><br/><span style='color:black; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Roboto;'>" & Fields!new_berrytexture.Value & " / " & Fields!new_flavour.Value & "</span>"
The font properties on the cell were different though.  Variety Name (snippet 1) had Arial at 10pt on the properties for the cell, and Eating Experience (snippet 2) had Myriad Pro Light at 14. Neither Arial or Myriad Pro appeared in the report, only Roboto, but there were some spacing issues. Once I changed snippet 1 to Myriad Pro at 14 pt., the text was aligned (right side of the picture.)
I'm glad I solved it, but can anyone tell me why this occured? I'd like to understand why the program worked this way.

